# Is there difference for adding the 'raise' statement or not?

Tags: python

```
import sys
try:
    f = open('myile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except OSError as err:
    print("OS Error: {0}".format(err))
except ValueError:
    print("Not integer")
except:
    print("Unexpected Error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    # raise
```

I found there is the same result with/without the raise statement. Could anyone can tell me the difference, please?
Thanks.

Comment: It may look the same, because it's the end of the script... There is still a difference because while the output may look the same, without raise it will appear to have finished successfully. With raise, it will be the exception ending your script.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify it clearly. I mean before I comment the 'raise' or after uncomment it, the test result is the same. I would like to know what's the difference between comment and uncomment.

Comment: Unless you never end in the catchall `except` it cannot be the same. If you don't end there, it of course would be, since that code is never reached. Otherwise... without `raise` the execution continues. With it, the last caught exception is reraised (and unless handled elsewhere, terminate).

Comment: Thanks very much:)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I found the answer in the official document: "If no expressions are present, `raise` re-raises the last exception that was active in the current scope. If no exception is active in the current scope, a `RuntimeError` exception is raised indicating that this is an error."